# Using AtomicInteger safely to check first

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

How can I do "check-then-act" in an `AtomicInteger` variable?
I.e. what is the most safe/best way to check the value of such a variable **first** and inc/dec depending on result?
E.g. (in high level)
`if(count < VALUE) count++;` //atomically using `AtomicInteger`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger

Comment: @Tomas:I don't see an answer to this at your link.Only how to use it.How can I do a check-then-act atomically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write a loop. Assuming that `count` is your `AtomicInteger` reference, you would write something like:

```
while(true)
{
    final int oldCount = count.get();
    if(oldCount >= VALUE)
        break;
    if(count.compareAndSet(oldCount, oldCount + 1))
        break;
}
```

The above will loop until either: (1) your `if(count < VALUE)` condition is not satisfied; or (2) `count` is successfully incremented. The use of `compareAndSet` to perform the incrementation lets us guarantee that the value of `count` is still `oldCount` (and therefore still less than `VALUE`) when we set its new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like this if you're using Java 8. It's thread safe and is being performed atomically.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
static final int COUNT = 10;

public int incrementUntilLimitReached() {
    return counter.getAndUpdate((n -> (n < COUNT) ? n + 1 : n));
}
```