# How do I automacially assign a variable in constructor while creating objects

Tags: java

Let's say we just have a simple object Person with int ID which identifies it. How can I give new ID value (+1) for each new instance of Person but in constructor of that class Person? (I use no DB for this)

Comment: @Mudu-s answer is thread-safe, while all other answers (which are exact duplicates including my answer, albeit mine was first) aren't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a static `AtomicInteger`:

```
final class Foo {
  private static final AtomicInteger seed = new AtomicInteger();
  private final int id;

  public Foo() {
    this.id = seed.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818753/17713

Answer (score 1):

use static variables; static variables aren't bound to class instances, rather to classes directly.

Example (in C#):

```
public class Person{
    public static int Increment = 1;

    public int ID;
    public Person(){
        this.ID = Increment;
        Increment++;
    }
}
```

This way all class instances will have unique ID-s (incremented by 1).

EDIT: This approach isn't thread-safe, see @Mudu's answer.

Comment: Except that's not thread-safe, nor is it a good idea to have public variables, nor is it following Java naming conventions.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is not thread-safe, but fine as long as you're not using multiple threads.

Comment: This solution doesn't take into consideration the threaded invocation of `Person` constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet - in his defence he has stated it is a C# example, I think you could offer a Java answer yourself?

Comment: @Neil: True - I missed that, having seen that it's a Java question. It's still not thread-safe or following good design principles in C# though :) (There's already a good Java answer suggesting AtomicInteger.)

Comment: @Mudu JonSkeet I commented on OP's question, I know it's not thread safe, that's why Mudu's answer was better.

Comment: I didn't edit my answer because Mudu already updated his with a working example.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili That's perfectly fine too, thread-safety is not needed everywhere, and the OP did not explicity as for it. I just found it worth being mentioned. :)

Comment: Yep, anyway, good job. @JonSkeet my fault, didn't see the java tag or I would post a java answer :)

Comment: Well I was only trying to figure out possible ways of achieving this, it wasn't specific. Thank you though for the multi thread warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
public class YourClass {
    private static int generalIdCount = 0;
    private int id;

    public YourClass() {
        this.id = generalIdCount;
        generalIdCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use static counting field which is shared accros all instances of `Person`:

```
class Person {
    private static int nextId = 1;
    private final int id;

    Person() {
        id = nextId++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static variable for the current counter value, and assign that to the ID when created...

```
public class Person {

    // same across all instances of this class
    static int currentCounter = 0;

    // only for this instance
    int personId;

    public Person(){
        personId = currentCounter;
        currentCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: True. I guess its up to the author to choose the answer which is most appropriate for their context, although a thread-safe answer like @Mudu will allow for all contexts regardless. Thanks for your feedback.