# What is the exact use of classes in java.util.concurrent.atomic package in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, java.util.concurrent

I am relatively new java. I am trying understand what are the usage of classes in the package:

> java.util.concurrent.atomic

I tried to understand the javaDoc for this package to get a grasp of it. But could'nt really make any sense out of it to when I should use these classes. Can someone give examples and more descriptions in simple words? thx

Comment: What couldn't you understand?

Comment: " prevent thread interference without resorting to synchronization" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Comment: Read the Trails, not the JavaDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Comment: The keyword is ["lock-free programming"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger

Comment: i was trying to understand this code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Synchronous_concurrency#Java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider 10 threads are incrementing int i (initialized at 0) and outputting the value the console. You can get something like this:

```
1
2
2
3
3
5
6
6
8
10
```

AtomicInteger, for example, ensures that each thread can increment or decrement the value **atomically**, ensuring that the write operation happens in a synchronized manner, and for 10 threads, the output would always be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Why do you skip from 3 to 5, and from 6 to 8 in your first example? Shouldn't 2 threads read a value at the same time and write the same value?