# Share method local variable value between threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, shared, barrier

I've been given the task to find the way to share a method's, involved in several threads, local variable, so it's value would be visible for every thread running this method.

Now my code look's like this:

```
public class SumBarrier2 implements Barrier {
    int thread_num;         // number of threads to handle
    int thread_accessed;    // number of threads come up the barrier
    volatile int last_sum;  // sum to be returned after new lifecyrcle
    volatile int sum;       // working variable to sum up the values

public SumBarrier2(int thread_num){
    this.thread_num = thread_num;
    thread_accessed = 0;
    last_sum = 0;
    sum = 0; 
}

public synchronized void addValue(int value){
    sum += value;
}

public synchronized void nullValues(){
    thread_accessed = 0;
    sum = 0;
}

@Override
public synchronized int waitBarrier(int value){
    int shared_local_sum;
    thread_accessed++;
    addValue(value);
    if(thread_accessed < thread_num){
        // If this is not the last thread
        try{
            this.wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
    } else if(thread_num == thread_accessed){
        last_sum = sum;
        nullValues();
        this.notifyAll();
    } else if (thread_accessed > thread_num ) {
        System.out.println("Something got wrong!");
    }       
    return last_sum;
}
```

}

So the task is to replace the class member

```
volatile int last_sum
```

with method's waitBarrier local variable, so it's value would be visible to all threads.

Any suggestions? 
Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks very much like a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) maybe just use one of those?

Answer (score 0):

In case the variable `last_sum` is updated by only one thread, then declaring it `volatile` will work. If not then you should look at [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

> An int value that may be updated atomically. See the
>   java.util.concurrent.atomic package specification for description of
>   the properties of atomic variables. An AtomicInteger is used in
>   applications such as atomically incremented counters, and cannot be
>   used as a replacement for an Integer. However, this class does extend
>   Number to allow uniform access by tools and utilities that deal with
>   numerically-based classes.

You can have the practical uses of `AtomicInteger` here: [Practical uses for AtomicInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger)