# Java Thread Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

This program runs 4 threads and searches for prime numbers from 1 to 100. Sometimes 2 threads are simultaneously attacking and numbers are repeated. I tried to synchronize the thread but I do not know how to do it well. Can I you can help? Sorry for my bad English

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EjemploThread1 extends Thread{

    static int numero=1;
    static ArrayList<Integer> primos = new ArrayList<Integer>() ; 

    public synchronized void run() {
        //try {
        while (numero < 100){
            numero++;

            if (!primos.contains(numero) && esPrimo(numero))
            {
                primos.add(numero);
            }

            notifyAll();

            //yield();
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    //MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        EjemploThread1 hilos = null;

        int n_hilos=4;

        //Crear los 4 Hilos
        for (int i=0;i<=n_hilos;i++) {
            hilos = new EjemploThread1();
            hilos.start();
        }

        for (int i=0;i<=n_hilos;i++) {
            hilos.join(); 
        }

        //cuando finalizen los hilos(join) continuara y mostrara el vector:
        System.out.println("\nVECTOR NUMEROS PRIMOS: ");
        for(int i=0; i < primos.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(primos.get(i) + " ");  
        }
    }

    //FUNCION SABER SI ES PRIMO
    public static boolean esPrimo(int numero)
     {
        for(int i=2; i<numero; i++)
        {
            if(numero % i == 0) return false; //no es primo
        }         
        return true; //es primo
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to divide up your search space among the `Thread`s when you initialize them so you have no overlap.  No clunky synchronization needed.  Something like this.

```
public class PrimeFinder implements Runnable {

    private int rangeStart;
    private int rangeEnd;

    public PrimeFinder(int start, int end) {
        rangeStart = start;
        rangeEnd = end;
    }

    public void run() {
        //check for primes where rangeStart <= x <= rangeEnd
    }
}
```

... then in `main`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new PrimeFinder(0, 25)).start();
    new Thread(new PrimeFinder(26, 50)).start();
    //and so on
}
```

As a side note, `synchronized`-ing the `run` method of your `Thread`s is useless.  Each `Thread` gets its own `run` method, so nothing else ever competes for that particular lock.

In response to your comment:

If you're *forced* to do it this way and don't want duplicate numbers added to your list, you can synchronize a wrapper method to add the primes:

```
public static synchronized void addPrime(int prime) {
    if(!primos.contains(prime)) {
        primos.add(prime);
    }
}
```

This will ensure that you get no duplicates.  Then in your `Thread` you would have:

```
if(esPrimo(numero)) {
    addPrime(numero);
}
```

Comment: I also thought like you do but I have to do it all running at once. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @TheBlackCode they are still running at once, just on chunks of data.

Comment: @TheBlackCode Updated my answer based on this. :)  The last method should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

instead of synchronizing `run()` you could synchronize the static arrayList primos:

```
 List primos = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This ensures that no two threads will test the same number

Answer (score 0):

I think synchronizing `run()` on a `Runnable` is never a good idea. I would simply declare numero as [`volatile`](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) or change its type to [`AtomicInteger`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger)