# Properties of AtomicInteger

Tags: java

If I have an `AtomicInteger` that starts out with 0, and it is incremented N times, is the final value guaranteed to be N? I guess it should be as that is the point of having `AtomicInteger` as a thread-safe counter, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have searched before asking this here. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger) question,

> There are two main uses of AtomicInteger:
>
> 1. As an atomic counter (incrementAndGet(), etc) that can be used by many threads concurrently
> 2. As a primitive that supports compare-and-swap instruction (compareAndSet()) to implement non-blocking algorithms.

So the answer to your question is `Yes`