# TestNg Customized report:

Tags: java, report, testng, customization

I am wondering how to get the count of total number of test cases which are being executed in a testng suite for displaying it in testng customized report.As of now we are able to get the passed failed and skipped tests. 
Please enlighten.

Comment: Just add them up...

Comment: Adding them is quite unstable, it does not remain in sync.

Comment: Use a AtomicInteger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Grasshoper's solutions sound good, just add them up, its quiet simple.

But if You using selenium/testng, try implementing methods by adding `implements ITestListener` to Your class and how have to implement this interface methods:

```
public interface ITestListener extends ITestNGListener {

  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result);

  public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result);

  public void onStart(ITestContext context);

  public void onFinish(ITestContext context);
```

and if You want to know exact number input code bellow to get all test methods:

```
public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    TestRunner tRunner = (TestRunner) context;
    ITestNGMethod[] testMethods = tRunner.getAllTestMethods();
    int count = testMethods.length; 
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes it works, @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext testContext) {
      super.onStart(testContext);
      int total=testContext.getAllTestMethods().length;

Comment: Glad I could help.